# image not stacking behind the features section?

Tags: css, z-index

[full project](https://codepen.io/bituustan/pen/jOrRqax)

```css
    .bo {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: 100px;
  #features {
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-12">
    <h1 class="heading">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
                    Download</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>Download</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-12">
    <img class="bo" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>


<!-- Features -->

<section id="features">
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <span class="icons"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> <br></span>


        <h3 class="tutorial">Easy to use.</h3>
        <p class="description">So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">

        <span class="icons"> <i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i> <br></span>

        <h3 class="tutorial">Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p class="description">We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">

        <span class="icons"> <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> </i> <br></span>

        <h3 class="tutorial">Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p class="description">Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

image is not getting stacked behind features section even when the features section has got a z index of one and image has gone none. and both are given a position of relative also still it is not getting stacked behind. help out to get it behind the features section

Comment: Can you fix your HTML? The start of your HTML is broken.

Comment: Can you add the `div` and `section` at the top of the HTML

Comment: You have an extra `i` closing tag here:

`<span class="icons"> <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> </i> <br></span>`

Comment: Try and change the `z-index` of features to something outrageous like 99 to see if something else is interfering

Comment: no effect of 99  i uploaded full project

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes yes bootstrap

Comment: If you give the class `bo` and the id `features` background colors, you will be able to see that the image is actually behind the features section.

Comment: yeah correct but how to solve this problem without adding bg color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       .bo {
      transform: rotate(25deg);
      height: 600px;
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 80px;
      top: 100px;
background-color:green;
      #features {
        margin: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
background-color:red;
```

after adding bg color actually it is getting stacked behind the features section but due to margin it is not seen use pesticide to view it and remove margin then problem will be solved